# Spring Data JPA + Hibernate + Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I use Spring Data JPA + Hibernate + Mysql. In one controller there is a for statement. In for statement I do search sql many times. During the search operation, in another controller I do  write sql. The database has changed. But the search sql's result didn't change.

Why the search sql's result didn't change, and how can I change the result?

Comment: Post code here that code would be helpful.

Comment: Well I guess this is related to the transaction isolation level you use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems).
It happens that the controller writing on the DB uses its own transation, while the controller who reads uses another transaction and so you have a phantom read

Comment: Hibernate will not commit your changes in DB unit you don't complete your first transaction.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I understand what you mean. But I want a phantom read. I add "@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)" on my search method. But the result is still same.

Comment: Hi @xiaocan, Could you paste some sample code ? I think it would be easy to understand and answer it ?